# CodeIgniter Controller 500 (Internal Server Error) Jquery Button

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to save some information into my database. If i click the submit button, I get only a 500 Server Error. Maybe you can help me?

Some details: I want to write a text into my input field. If I click the submit button, I want to save the text into the database.

If I click the submit button, I get a 500 Error in my console.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) sites/testsite/Dashboard/create
```

controllers/Dashboard

```
class Dashboard extends CIF_Controller {
    public function create(){

            $chattext = $this->input->post('chattext');
            $this->Users_model->create($chattext);
        }
}
```

Models / Users_model:

```
class Users_model extends CIF_model
{
    public function create($chattext){

            $this->db->set('chattext', $chattext);
            $this->db->insert('chattext');
        }
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="chattext" id="chattext" placeholder="Type message...">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="submit" type="button" "btn btn-default">Send</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

This is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('Dashboard/create');?>",
                data:$("#myForm").serialize(),
                success: function (response) {

                    alert(response);

                    }
                ,})
        ;})


    $("#neuerEintrag").click(function(){

        $("#form").removeClass("collapse");
    });    

    ;});
```

Database Details:

```
Table: chattext
           - chat_id
           - chattext
```

Comment: Is it on purpose that your controller is extending CIF_Controller, and your model CIF_Model? Normally controllers would extend CI_Controller and models CI_Model. That's why I'm asking, because this would be a problem unless you have a CIF_Controller and CIF_Model.

Comment: another point is what is export of this  ? ``<?php echo site_url('Dashboard/create'); ?>``

Comment: <?php echo site_url('Dashboard/create'); ?  need to connect to the controller

Comment: Did you set the base_url in config.php also try it like `url: "<?php echo base_url('dashboard/create');?>"`

Comment: And Not sure what this means CIF_ should be CI_Model and CI_Controller